# How can we control suggestions with MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

i am using MultiAutoCompleteTextView  for showing suggestions, i used a space tokenizer.but currently it shows predictions when 1 and 3 index of the words and then i set threshold to 2 and now its in the pattern 2,4 index. how can we show predictions based on string length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TextWatcher class and pass the new length of the string to the threshold method so whenever the text changes MultiAutoCompleteTextView will show predictions based on string length.

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView multiAutocomplete = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) 
                              findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);

            multiAutocomplete
            .setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.SpaceTokenizer());

    multiAutocomplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            String newText = s.toString();
            multiAutocomplete.setThreshold(newText.length());
        }

    });
```

Hope, this will help you!